# I am trying to extract command line arguments from a file. I am having trouble splitting on fields that are quoted with escaped quotes inside

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, text-parsing

I have the following file

argsfile

```
-e "my_var=\"this string has spaces\"" -e "my_var2=\"this one too\""
```

I need to be able to split this input into an array like so:

`['-e', '"my_var=\"this string has spaces\""', '-e', '"my_var2=\"this one too\""' ]`

I think this would also be fine

`['-e', 'my_var="this string has spaces"', '-e', 'my_var2="this one too"' ]`

In other words, I want to preserve the spaces within fields that are quoted, and I want to ignore escaped quotes for the purposes of splitting.

Python or Perl answers would also be great as long as I can execute them inside Bash code.

I've tried awk with FPAT of varying degrees of complexity, grep, read, and xargs. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with any of these tools or any combination of them.

For example, `grep -Eo "\S+|'.*'|\".*\"` is too greedy: it splits on the first -e just fine, but then it treats the entire rest of the string as one element because of the double quotes surrounding `my_var=\"this string has spaces\""', '-e', '"my_var2=\"this one too\"`.

Other things I've tried like xargs or awk also end up getting results that chop off the first -e and then just push the rest of the string into the first element of the array, or I get results that split on whitespace regardless of quotes.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Why do you show the desired array in Python syntax when you want it in Bash?

Comment: No particular reason, I just thought it was a more universal way to represent arrays of strings, not just Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For safety's sake I would use something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(grep -oE '"(\\"|[^"])*"|[^ ]+' argsfile)
```

The resulting bash `array` will then be:

```bash
array=(
    [0]='-e'
    [1]='"my_var=\"this string has spaces\""'
    [2]='-e'
    [3]='"my_var2=\"this one too\""'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this input is quoted in shell manner, it is best handled by the shell:

```
eval name=($(<argsfile))
```

There you have the array `name`.

Comment: simple, but dangerous; even `declare -a name="($(<argsfile))"` won't be safer